# Beats Studio Buds don't connect after iOS 15.3 update

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones

Last night I updated my iPhone 8 to iOS 15.3. This morning I noticed that I had some trouble connecting my Beats Studio Buds to my phone.

### Expected Behavior

Normally, when I open my Beats case and pull one of the earbuds out, it automatically connects to my phone and sound starts playing from the ear buds. After listening for a while, if I put one earbud back in the case, the audio pauses and they are disconnected.

### Current Behavior

When I pull an earbud out of the case, it does not connect to my phone right away. What seems to work right now is that I have to pull out both earbuds, press/hold the button to activate ANC and then go into my Bluetooth settings and connection to `Beats Studio Buds`, which displays as "Not Connected". After waiting a little while, it eventually connects and audio is playable. Once I put my earbuds back in the case, I have to repeat this process to listen again.

If my earbuds are in the case, and my phone is on, when I open the case near my phone, a popup opens showing the buds/case with their battery percentages, similar to what you might see when a new pair of earbuds are brought near a phone.

### What I have tried

I removed the Beats from the Bluetooth menu with the "Forget" option. I then did a reset [as described on Apple's Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212505). I then tried to pair it up again as a new device. My phone asked if I wanted to connect and all I got was a red exclamation point, indicating some unknown error.

Answer (score 1):

I do not own a pair of Beats Studio Buds, but **IF** the Bluetooth settings are similar (which they seem to be) to those of the AirPods, you may want to have a look at Bluetooth settings.

When your Beats are connected, go to the **Bluetooth Preference Pane** and click on the i next to the device name. Look for **Connect to this iPhone** and check to see if it is set to **Automatically**.